# Image of each topic the link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The problem is that only displays the image of the latest posting.
Each link should display the image of your post.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
var link = $('h2.topic-title > a').attr('href');
jQuery.get(link, function(data) {
    imglink = jQuery('.wrap .post .entry-content div img', data).attr('src');
    jQuery('h2.topic-title > a').after('<div class="verimg"><img src="' + imglink + '" /></div>');

});});
```

What I want is that he take a picture of each post and put next to the link.
However he is repeating the same image to all links.

Answer (score 0):

This has to be an issue with your selectors.

```
$('table > tbody  > tr > td > h2.topic-title > a')
```

This is an awful way to select an anchor tag in a table. You would probably be fine with just

```
$('h2.topic-title > a')
```

I would personally just add a class (say, `.img-post`) to each anchor I want to select and target them with `$('.img-post')`

Comment: What I want is that he take a picture of each post and put next to the link.
However he is repeating the same image to all links.